# jquery sortable problem with ie

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable, internet-explorer-7

i am using jquery to sort my lists and i have run into a dead end. First, I checked the jquery site if theirs work on ie7, thats great, it does. next, i checked mine without the styles(so there possibly wont be anything that's intercepting or affecting jquery stuff). but i still get this weird error in ie7

when you sort items in the inner list(i have nested lists) they overlap each other, destroying the layout. if you sort the contianer lists, they work fine! here's a jsfiddle of what i mean:

http://jsfiddle.net/GDUpa/

note that if you drag demonstration one or two spots(in ie), it will overlap with the other links. BUT if you drag POC (it will select the whole thing including the links under it), it works fine!

is something wrong with my markup?

*EDIT*
I've checked and it seems IE is messing up with nested sortable lists. is there anyone who can point me to the right direction on how to support ie7's bitchiness?

Comment: would you provide some code to look at?

Comment: It seems to be broken in FF 3.0.18 on CentOS as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that there are two draggables right on top of each other (the outer `ul` and the inner `li`).  If you add a `handle` to the outer `ul` such that it only can drag when on the `p.test-category` it seems to fix the problem.  I added some CSS so that it is easier to see the tree but it works without it as well.

http://jsfiddle.net/GDUpa/7/

Comment: DUDE YOU ARE THE MAN! i was about to hack it so that IE users won't be able to sort by categories lol. thanks thanks.